# Does Zend disable inlineScript helper in ajax context?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have some javascript that is only required when a certain jQuery dialog is loaded.  I have put it in an external file and referenced it in the controller as:

```
$this->view->inlineScript()->appendFile('/theme/flat/scripts/new-post.js');
```

In my new-post.ajax.phtml file I have the following line:

```
<?=$this->inlineScript();?>
```

But I just can't get it to work.  There are no script tags or content inserted.

If I put the same code in a non-ajax controller and view it works fine.

Is it possible that the ajaxContext action helper disables the inlineScript view helper?  Why?  And is there a way around it?  (I have quite a few snippets I am pulling in with ajax, and each has its own javascript code).

Comment: change chance you are disabling the layout for ajax requests and just outputting the view instead?

Comment: Andrew, I am outputting just the view, but the view includes the instruction to render the inlineScript helper...